# Overriding insertInManagedObjectContext: will have no effects on child entities in mogenerator : why and how to do?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, inheritance, mogenerator

In the methods `insertInManagedObjectContext:` provided by `mogenerator`, there is no call to any super methods.

I wonder why.

Indeed,

- Imagine I have two entities : `ParentEntity` and `ChildEntity` ; of course, `ParentEntity` is the parent entity of `ChildEntity`.
- Then, I override the `insertInManagedObjectContext:` of the `ParentEntity`.
- But then, when I create a `ChildEntity`, none of my changes will be taken in account !!

I was wondering why such a choice and maybe a solution.

---

---

My need is to create a super  entity with children and that this super entity have two insert methods. I want these two insert methods to be usable by the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they just didn't think of it the same way you do.

As for what you can do, why not implement your own method to take the place of `insertInManagedObjectContext:` and have it call super's implementation? Generate the files, then put your new method in `ChildEntity.m`, and have that version call super's version. You can't use the same method name since `_ChildEntity.m` will have one that doesn't call super's version. So, use some other method name.