# awakeFromInsert called twice with nested contexts

Tags: objective-c, core-data, mogenerator, magicalrecord-2.1

This project uses Mogenerator and Magical Record. I have tracked down a bug to the fact that `awakeFromInsert` is getting called twice. Once for each of my contexts I presume. This is an issue because I need to listen for NSNotifications on this NSManagedObject like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    // Listen for a return from background mode
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteringForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

But awakeFromInsert get's called twice which is rather annoying. I want to call a method ONCE when my NSManagedObject is first created.

After searching [this solution seems to make a lot of sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147361/321123). However I can't see how I can add a category onto NSManagedObject when using Mogenerator and MagicalRecord. Without some complex overriding.

In MagicalRecord `MR_createEntity` calls

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(insertInManagedObjectContext:)]) 
    {
        id entity = [self performSelector:@selector(insertInManagedObjectContext:) withObject:context];
        return entity;
    }
```

Is there a neater solution to this issue?

Comment: Mogenerator creates two classes per entity, a "machine" class and a "human" class. You can add methods to the "human" class as you like, without the need for a category.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I already do that. I guess the issue here is that I need MagicalRecord to call my new method not insertInManagedObjectContext as shown above.

Comment: I don't yet understand the relation between the "awakeFromFetch called twice" problem and `insertInManagedObjectContext:` (which may be my fault). - But can't you override `insertInManagedObjectContext:` in the "human" entity class?

Comment: Sorry Martin my bad the code examples should all show awakeFromInsert. Which gets called by insertInManagedObjectContext: then for every context that gets saved by MR. AFAIK so far.

Comment: It seems that overriding insertInManagedObjectContext: with Mogenerator doesn't work too well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430005/overriding-insertinmanagedobjectcontext-will-have-no-effects-on-child-entities

Comment: The answer to that question states that you *can* override it in your entity class.

Answer (score 2):

Ok well this feels very hacky but appears to work. I created the following class methods on my human readable NSManagedObject class:

```
+ (id)insertInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc_ {

    JWBoard *newobject = [super insertInManagedObjectContext:moc_];
    [JWBoard awakeFromCreate:newobject];
    return newobject;
}

+ (void)awakeFromCreate:(JWBoard *)board
{
    // do setup stuff & add observers
}
```

Open to much better solutions!

Comment: Thanks for this code -- works great as long as you also use  MOGenerator's `insertInManagedObjectContext` -- I did have to search my project and analyze everywhere I used entityDescriptionForName to make sure I wasn't doing an insert the non-MOGenerator way.

Answer (score 0):

> Open to much better solutions!

I wish!  Would have been easy enough for apple to *not* invoke awakeFromInsert, or to at least provide a flag that's true in the context of a "parentProcessSaveRequest."  If you look at the call stack for the not-first calls to `awakeFromInsert`, the stack always contains `parentProcessSaveRequest`.

Here's some ***terrible*** code proving as much:

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert 
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];

    NSArray* stackArray = [NSThread callStackSymbols];
    for (NSString* method in stackArray)
    {
        if ([method rangeOfString:@"_parentProcessSaveRequest"].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            NSLog(@"Parent insert %@",self.objectID);
            return;
        }        
    }
    NSLog(@"First insert %@",self.objectID);
    // Initialize here

}
```

And the log output -- the objectId stays the same:

```
2014-05-19 20:53:52.964 myApp[1891:a01f] First insert 0x6000000326c0 <x-coredata:///MyEntity/t496E9B17-E170-4A7C-B7D4-7D8B92433E1C2>
2014-05-19 20:53:53.531 myApp[1891:303] Parent insert 0xdca8000eb <x-coredata://7274869F-4BF3-4B8A-9270-A64E54476AAD/MyEntity/p14122>
2014-05-19 20:53:53.537 myApp[1891:303] Parent insert 0xdca8000eb <x-coredata://7274869F-4BF3-4B8A-9270-A64E54476AAD/MyEntity/p14122>
```

Seems to work for saving to any of the nested contexts that I have, ugly as it is.

Unfortunately I cant figure any *reasonable* way to determine whether awakeFromInsert is being called in the context of a parentProcessSaveRequest.  Come on, Apple!  Give us a flag here.

Answer (score 0):

here is the simplest one:
when parentContext is null, means when this context is saved you can do you custom logic, for example incrementing table number

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
 {

     if (!self.managedObjectContext.parentContext) {
         //setting tableNumber

         [self willChangeValueForKey:@"number"];
         [self setPrimitiveNumber:tableNumber];
         [self didChangeValueForKey:@"number"];
    }

 }
```