# Cocoa Binding only for retrieval

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have an `NSTableView` with few controls. All are bind to array-controller whose entity is a a subclass of `NSManagedObject` (or in simple words an entity of core data).

There is one checkbox, which is getting its value from the entity.

Now the problem is I don't want the checkbox value updating to coredata directly. The saving should happen only on "Save" button action.

Any help on how to proceed this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can segregate contexts, bind to A have B observing A then when you save A you get the notification which will contain the changes on B, then you merge it. I can provide code... of course the to-disk changes don't happen until you save the context...

Answer (score 0):

Use `[context save:nil];` when the save button is pressed, `[context rollback];` otherwise.

Comment: On checkbox click only it is updating the coredata. Then I have some delegates and notifications that do other processes. I dont want the checkbox's action to trigger to update the coredata.

Comment: You could dissociate the checkbox from the binding and inform it by your own datasource, e.g. an array. Then, when it is time to save, iterate though the changed values.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you could do it, and they're all hacks in terms of the effort for *one* checkbox.

However if you have an entire form that a user is editing, you can just create a child ManagedObjectContext, bind the checkbox and the rest of the form to *that* context and merge or discard the entirety of the changes within that context depending on whether the user hits save or cancel.

I am a big fan of [this Cocoanetics article on Core Data context stacks](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/).  You may actually want your entire GUI running off a main-thread context, with saves (when confirmed by the user) pushed up to a writer context and persisted to disk if you are trying to work around the default of immediate persistence.

One *huge* issue I've discovered with child contexts and class-backed entities is[`awakeFromInsert` getting called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893775/awakefrominsert-called-twice-with-nested-contexts/23751067#23751067), so be aware that you may have to deal with other complexities.